# How to get focus to selected window if it exists in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I have application with "About" button. When it is clicked, I want to open a new window with credits. But If the window is already open, I want only bring it to focus (first plan), instead of opening next instance. The first part, to prevent opening multiple windows is easy:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var existingWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<About>().Any();
        if (!existingWindow)
        {
            About p = new About();
            p.Show();
        }
    }
```

So first I check if any windows of type `About` exist, and if it is `false` I create new instance and show it. But how to implement the second part? I mean `else` statement if the window `About` is already open, to bring it to the first plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `Activate` method.  Here's how I would write it:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var existingWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<About>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (existingWindow != null)
    {
        existingWindow.Activate();
    }
    else
    {
        About p = new About();
        p.Show();
    }
}
```

I'm using `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Any()` to get the first window of type `About` or `null` if no such window exists.  Then I check if `existingWindow` is not null and call `Activate()` or make a new one accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely this. I was trying with `Activate` method but I was not aware I can get handle so easy way. Thank you!